# How to listen to both user edits and changes made in code for textfield in ExtJs4?

Tags: extjs, event-handling, extjs4, textfield

I know that I can add a listener to the `change` event, but it will fire only when user changes the value. Is there a way to setup a similar listener for programmatic change as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use setValue() method that should fire your change event.

Answer (score 1):

You can fire event after programmatic changes.

```
cmp.fireEvent('change', cmp, newValue, oldValue)
```